# VB.NET: Silently failing?

Tags: vb.net, ide

I don't like the fact that VB.NET is silently failing on an operation if something goes wrong:

```
    Dim n(10) As String
    n(11) = "blah"
```

I do not want to handle such situation with a Try/Catch/Finally, that would be an overkill. 
I will stumble over such situations while testing my application during development.

But the fact that VB.NET simply skips over this error is a bit annoying.
Can I change the IDE so that it breaks in this line?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next`? Do you have a `Catch` block elsewhere?

Comment: change your exceptions settings in your IDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click Debug, Exceptions, then check all of the checkboxes.

The debugger will not break whenever any exception is thrown anywhere, even if it is subsequently handled.

Comment: Hmmm, can you please tell me where to find it? I expected it to be under "Options"->"Debugging", but I don't see it there.

Comment: LOL, after 20 minutes of searching I already found it. "Debug" is located on the top menu right besides "Team" in VS2010.